# Для запуска требуется получить разрешение com.mediatek.permission.CTA_ENABLE_WIFI

Tags: android, android-permissions

Для запуска моего приложение для телефона Blackview BV9500Plus, видимо существует внутреннее разрешение - com.mediatek.permission.CTA_ENABLE_WIFI. Как запросить данное разрешение? Стандартные разрешения для wi-fi

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

прописаны, но не помогают
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте CHANGE_WIFI_STATE и/или CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Добавление CHANGE_WIFI_STATE и/или CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE не помогло, добавил проблемные разрешения в исключение и все заработало)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]